# i cannot find a listener for a listview when data(total count) changes

Tags: android, listview, listener

Why isnt there a listener for a listview that will tell the listener when the item count has changed?

I did try to search for it, but did not found any listener for this.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are the one who is changing the item count, via your adapter. You can track count changes yourself, and trigger whatever listener you want yourself.

Comment: so create your own listener in the adapter?

Comment: @cc2k: There, or wherever else it may make sense (e.g., in the code that is updating the adapter). Adapters do not get new data magically -- some code of yours is telling the adapters about the data changes. It could be that code's responsibility to detect a change in counts and take appropriate actions. That is up to you.

Comment: yeah, made ondatachange method with includes adapter.ondatasetchanged. thx

Comment: @CommonsWare what is about delay between `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and the moment when new item really appears in ListView? I mean that I think that I can't call this method in one line, and in the next line try to find newly added item in ListView (to set listener on it) ?

Comment: @B-GangsteR: There is no concept of "find... item in ListView". Hence, your scenario does not exist.